# C# How can I ensure a HashSet<object> of children references the same objects?

Tags: c#

There is a Sku class, each of which can have up to about 10 dimensional Variants.

```
public class Variant
{
    public Guid Id;
    public int Length;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public HashSet<Variant> ChildrenVariants;
    public bool IsVariantEligible;

    public Variant()
    {
        ChildrenVariants = new HashSet<Variant>();
    }

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return ChildrenVariants.Count > 0; }
    }
}

public class Sku
{
    public ObservableCollection<Variant> Variants;
    public bool IsSkuEligible;

    public void CheckEligible()
    {
        var parentVars = Variants.Where(v => v.HasChildren);

        foreach (var parentVar in parentVars)
        {
            // TEST: all return false
            var isEqual1 = object.ReferenceEquals(ineligibleKeyVars.First(), parentVar.ChildrenVariants.First());
            var isEqual2 = object.ReferenceEquals(DimensionVariants[1], parentVar.ChildrenVariants.First());
            var isEqual3 = DimensionVariants[1] == DimensionVariants[0].ChildrenVariants.First();

            // TEST: returns true
            var isEqual4 = DimensionVariants[0] == parentVars.First();

            // ACTUAL: code that I actually need to work here:
            if (parentVar.ChildrenVariants.All(c => !c.IsVariantEligible))
            {
                IsSkuEligible = false;
                return;
            }
        }

        IsSkuEligible = true;
    }
}
```

Variants can have children variants, and I want the references contained in each Variant's ChildrenVariants to reference the same objects as referenced by the elements in the Sku's Variants property value.

Other code not shown here allows the user to mark a Variant is ineligible and then the SKU gets re-checked by calling CheckEligible(). What's throwing me off is that I would expect the first 3 isEqual test lines to be true, but they're not. They're false.

For my test, I have a Sku with two Variants, VariantA and VariantB. VariantA is ineligible, and that has a child VariantB that is eligible. VariantA's ChildrenVariants has one element, VariantB.

When the user checks a box in the UI to mark VariantB as ineligible, it correctly changes the IsVariantEligible property on VariantB to false. However, VariantA.ChildrenVariants.First().IsVariantEligible does NOT change. I don't know why.

I think that the crux of this problem is that the references in ChildrenVariants are somehow not the same references as in the Variants property on the Sku. I've used the debugger to prove this. I can set a breakpoint and edit the IsVariantEligible property and it changes it on the object in Variants but not the object in the parent Variant's ChildrenVariants. I can then not use the

Is there a subtlety in ObservableCollection, HashSet, foreach, or the LINQ queries that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if more code would be helpful to show. This is part of a very large solution, so I tried to distill it down to what I thought is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Also, do you mean to use `Any` instead of `All`?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of `public` access modifiers. You're right about `HasChildren`, I forgot to add the `get { }` to make it a property and I fixed it to return `bool` rather than `int`. As for the `Any`, no it's supposed to be `All`. the family of `Variant`s and therefore the `Sku` is only ineligible if all children of a parent are ineligible. In other words, as long as a single child `Variant` is eligible, the whole family is eligible and will not make the `Sku` ineligible.

Comment: I have since found this article by Jon Skeet. https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html This may contain the answer. Thank you @RufusL for your replies. :)